# Codenameone - generate AppStoreInfo.plist Build Hint

Tags: ios, codenameone, itmstransporter

Is there a build hint in CodenameOne to generate AppStoreInfo.plist when submiting a RELEASE iOS BUILD?

I've successfully generated the IPA file, but when I try to upload to App Store with (iTMSTTransporter tool) I need that file to upload from Windows/Linux.

`iTMSTransporter.cmd -assetfile myApp.ipa -u appDevUser -m upload`

And the error I receive is:

> ```
> Unable to generate a software package on Windows. Export an AppStoreInfo.pli
> ```

st from Xcode, and use the -assetDescription option.

If i'm not mistaken, that AppStoreInfo.plist file is all I need to be able to upload from WINDOWS to App Connect.

Check

https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html#apdAe41970bd

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/public/Transporter__Windows/bin

Answer (score 0):

Edited: This file is supported and generated automatically when building.

Right now we don't support that file. As a workaround you can build in xcode but we're aware that this isn't a practical workaround. Please file an issue and we'll try to include that issue in the releases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that I don't have XCode, as I don't have a MAC. So before looking into virtual mac options, I wanted to explore any chance to upload from windows.
Will file an issue.

Comment: I'm aware of that. That's why I asked for the issue so we can look at adding that functionality. This is a relatively new capability/requirement from Apple but it's indeed great. Up until now we were looking at building our own upload solution so this is pretty great!